# How to inform clients connected to a NodeJS WebsocketServer when database changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, websocket, persistence

I'm trying to create a WebSocketServer (WSS) with NodeJS and Socket.io. I have a backend solution, where people can create and edit database entries. I want to create a front-end application, which connects to the WSS and change it's view, whenever something in a database changed.

I'm pretty new to the whole WebSocket topic. Currently I have no idea, how to keep the WSS informed, whenever the database changes, so it can push data to the clients.

As said, I want to inform all clients, when something in the database is created or updated.

Comment: Can you explain how your database is being updated? as per my understanding we can't setup an event on nodejs which will be called from database.

Comment: Your database is updated from your server, therefore you always know when an operation is performed. It doesn't change on its own. Just do a `io.emit()` whenever you write, update or delete in the database. I don't see the difficulty here

Comment: @JeremyThille The database is update from a different application, not from the WSS itself

Comment: So, you want to monitor an entirely external database, completely independent from your own server, and notify people whenever the database changes?

Comment: Exactly. The database is located on a cluster. The application our users use, just updates the database. My WSS should somehow "listen" to changes. I read something about ServerSideEvents, but not exactly sure.